# Executing rails server not working on windows, shows "usage" text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When executing ***rails server*** or ***rails s***, I get the following returned instead of the server starting up

[image]

I've been following the writings of [Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) in order to set this up, when I ran into this confusing roadblock. Wondered if anyone had an idea of why it is acting like server isn't an understood command when it seems to be everywhere else?

Dev enviroment:

ruby 2.0.0p247
rails 4.0.0
windows 7
eclipse juno for JavaEE

Comment: Did you cd into your actual project directory?

Comment: @MarekLipka I did yes. The directory specified above is the directory that my project would reside. Tried it outside just for completeness with the same result.

Comment: Did you actually execute `rails new app_name`? Can you show the contents of the directory where you're trying to start `rails server`?

Comment: @koffeinfrei I did,although running rails new app_name again with a different app, then cd'ing into that new folder it worked. I tried it in the first project, and it came up with that display above. Perhaps something went left when it should have went right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a permissions problem?

You can run `ls -l` on the directory to check you permissions access

To give read write and execute for all files use `chmod -R <permissionsettings> <dirname>`

777 means all permissions